# Magento 2 tax rates based on city

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation

In **Magento 1** I am **able** to see tax rate options based on **city** but in **Magento2** I am **unable** to see the tax rates based on the **cities**. 
While creating tax rate i am unable to see city field but in one with city i am able to create

Comment: What do you want? please ask your question with little more information.

Comment: you can modify from tax rate configuration